# How to overwrite column values in bigquery existing table

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I need to overwrite/update column values in bigquery.
The problem with solution bellow is it loads lots of data every time need to upload few records.
Need a more optimal solution which will only upload the id's that matches.

Extra: it would be even better if it could check if the value is the same, if not it doesn't update the record.
I would think it would reduce even more with load

table 1:

```
name   id    value
jose   1     10
jack   5     15
lex    4   12
```

table 2:

```
id   value
1    200
2    200
3    700
4    800
5    200
```

Query:

```
select
t1.name,
t1.id,
t2.value

from table 1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

The example in the link bellow creates a new table, so doesn't work. It need to update values in the existing table.

[changing column values in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073333/changing-column-values-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 1):

You got this wrong.

In BigQuery **you pay what you read** and not what you write. So if you need to read a lot of rows to compare, for every read you pay, and the write is free. So you should reduce with a WHERE logic the number of items you "read" to reduce your costs.